# What is LDAP used for?

Tags: ldap, protocol

I've been going over some LDAP tutorials, but I can't imagine why would i use that? I figured that it is some kind of a list of all users and usergroups, but where is it different than system users and usergroups.

Can someone please provide some real-world example?

Thanks a lot :D

Comment: If you use Active Directory then you're already using an implementation of LDAP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't imagine what to use it for, you don't need it.

It can be used for a lot of things, however.

- Central user database for multiple systems. This is the most-often used scenario.
- Keeping user settings
- Address books
- Storing configuration data (like puppet manifests)
- Arbitrary databases for tree-organized data

and countless other possibilities.

Comment: Thanks, no i dont need it, i was just reading about it and didn't quite understand. thanks